# How can I create an imbricated dictionnary from another dictionnary that has different numbers of element for each key combined with a function

Tags: python, data-structures

I have a problem for inialize an imbricated dictionnary from another one that has different numbers  of element for each key.

So basically my first dictionnary is like :
{0: [238, 159], ..., 7 [290, 311, 8], 67 [135, 173, 69, 68, 70, 71], ...} it shows where you can go from the key you're choosing, for example from the key 0 you can go to points 238 and 159.
And I have a funtion Time that returns me how much time it takes to go from a point to another one.

The result I want is like:
{0: {238: Time(0, 238), 159: Time(0, 159)}, ..., {7: {290: Time(7, 290), 311: Time(7 ,311), 8: Time(7, 8)}, ...}

As I said all key (0-375) from the 1st dictionnary has between 1-6 elements in their list.
And I took all the data from a .txt

*Sorry for my english, don't hesitate to ask me questions if you don't understand, also I can show you my code but its kinda long to understand so I tried to simplify

Comment: There is no [tag:python] in this question. See how to create a [mcve]. Edit the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made a sample Time class you can replace it with yours.
newDict will be the dictionary in the form that you are looking for.

```
class Time:
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def printXY(self):
        return ("Time (" + str(self.x) + "," + str(self.y) + ")")
def solution():
    dict = {0:[238,159], 
            7:[290,311,8], 
            67:[135, 173, 69, 68, 70, 71]}
    
    newDict = {}
    
    for key, value in dict.items():
        tempDict = {}
        for v in value:
            tempDict[v] = Time(key,v)
        newDict[key] = tempDict
    
    for key,value in newDict.items():
        print("For key = " + str(key))
        for k,v in value.items():
            print(str(k) + ":"+ v.printXY())
        print ("")
'''
OUTPUT:

For key = 0
238:Time (0,238)
159:Time (0,159)

For key = 7
290:Time (7,290)
311:Time (7,311)
8:Time (7,8)

For key = 67
135:Time (67,135)
173:Time (67,173)
69:Time (67,69)
68:Time (67,68)
70:Time (67,70)
71:Time (67,71)
'''
```

Comment: tysm, didnt think about using classes

Comment: If your question is answered please mark it as answered. :)